# How to integrate an index.php file (in which is a form) into a fan gate, so it's just visible for fans?

Tags: facebook, integrate

how to integrate an index.php file (in which is a form) into a fan gate (so it's just visible for fans)?
I already got the fangate php file but I don't know how to integrate another php file in the fangate.

It doesn't work with " include "index.php"; " because everytime someone clicks the Send/Participate button of the form in the index.php file a new white/empty site is loading. But the index.php file works without the fan gate integration.

Has someone had the same problem or has anyone an idea what I can do to solve the problem?

Comment: How about providing some code for us to review ans see what you are doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An immediate solution would be to modify your fan_gate.php file so it will redirect the fans to the index.php file

However, the better solution would be to fix your form. It should work fine with include, I have several includes in my app and it works just fine. The problem is probably with your form's target (action). Change it to fan_gate.php if you use include.

If it still doesn't work, can you give me a link to the page?

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer.
But how do I redirect the fans to the index.php file?

Comment: either with a php header or by echoing the meta redirect tag. http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php or http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_redirect